# mouse ball is not working on ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu on virtual box. mouse key click is working well but, the mouse ball is not working for up and down operations. please suggest if you have similar problem.

Comment: So, (A) when you move the mouse towards or away from you, the motion is not translated into screen motion of the cursor, is that correct?  Or, are you instead (B) having problems with the roller on the top of the mouse, the scroll wheel, as shown at http://technoworries.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/mouse-scroll-wheel.jpg ? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Does your mouse actually have a ball? Many do not, are solid state and use an LED/camera combination. If it has a ball, twist off the ball's retaining ring then remove the ball. There will be two or more rollers inside; clear any accumulation of rubber particles and dirt from the rollers, making sure to spin the rollers back and forth through at full rotation. Put the ball back in, lock in in with the retaining ring, and try again.